# Error in Mallet Java

Tags: java, lda, topic-modeling, mallet

I want to do topic modelling , So, I ran the below command :-

```
bin\mallet train-topics --input web.mallet --output-state output-file.gz
```

It tells me :- Topic modeling currently only supports feature sequences: use --keep-sequence option when importing data.

When I add --keep-sequence my command becomes :-

```
bin\mallet train-topics --input web.mallet --output-state output-file.gz --keep-sequence
```

This gives below error :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized option 4: --keep-sequence
        at cc.mallet.util.CommandOption$List.process(CommandOption.java:345)
        at cc.mallet.util.CommandOption.process(CommandOption.java:146)
        at cc.mallet.topics.tui.Vectors2Topics.main(Vectors2Topics.java:201)
```

What should I do? I am running this first time. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The `train-topics` command is for running a model on a previously imported Mallet data file. The `--keep-sequence` option is used for the data import phase, using the `import-file` or `import-dir` command.